# Idle time of available EBS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have many EBS volumes in 'available' state, want to remediate those volumes.But I am trying to figure out how long these are in available state from 'in-use' state. let's say if ebs volume is in available for more than 40 days, I want to delete, but want to make sure before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to collect this information over time and review it.  You can't query the API for it directly.

See the docs for the [AWS Config Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/config-concepts.html) for how to collect this information over time.

Or, just take final snapshots of the volumes and then delete them.  It is almost always more cost effective to keep a snapshot than to keep a volume provisioned.

Or, rename the volumes to `i-am-going-to-be-deleted-${future_date}-so-rename-me-if-you-need-me`.  Any volume still named that when the date arrives can be torched.

I saved the worst idea for last.  How many times I have done this, I will not admit to publicly. :)